# Hibernate Criteria -- return records where column is distinct

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Sample database table:

1. ID = 1, msgFrom = 'Hello', foobar = 'meh'
2. ID = 2, msgFrom = 'Goodbye', foobar = 'comments'
3. ID = 3, msgFrom = 'Hello', foobar = 'response'

Sample desired output (generated by hibernate query):

1. ID = 1, msgFrom = 'Hello', foobar = 'meh'
2. ID = 2, msgFrom = 'Goodbye', foobar = 'comments'

In the above example, the third record would be excluded from the results since the msgFrom column is the same. Let's say the Java/Hibernate class is called Message. I would like the results to be returned as a list of Message objects (or Objects that can be cast to Message, anyway). I want to use the Criteria API if possible. I saw this example on SO and it seems similar but I cannot implement it correctly as of yet.

```
 select e from Message e 
    where e.msgFrom IN (select distinct m.msgFrom 
                          from Message m
                          WHERE m.msgTo = ? 
                          AND m.msgCheck = 0");
```

The reason I am doing this is to have the filtering of distinct records done on the database, so I am not interested in answers where I have to filter anything on the application server.

edit: Article showing basically what I want to do. http://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/sql-distinct-on-one-column-only/

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196243/using-hibernates-criteria-and-projections-to-select-multiple-distinct-columns will help ?

Comment: @aishwarya I already saw that. That post is combining two columns and making it distinct. Not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @KyleM, sure, i meant have you tried setting the projection `Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id.msgFrom"))` ?

Comment: where was id declared? How about this... if you know what you want me to try, post an answer and i'll try the exact syntax you give me.

Comment: @aishwarya And that isn't bc I'm being lazy. I don't understand why you are suggesting what you are. What is "id" in your example? Where was it declared? It would probably just be easier if you posted a response and clarified what you are suggesting I try, and why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this and let me know

```
DetachedCriteria msgFromCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Message.class);
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.groupProperty("messageFrom"));
properties.add(Projections.min("id"),"id");
msgFromCriteria.setProjection(properties);

Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(Message.class);
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[]{"messageFrom","id"}, 
    msgFromCriteria));
List<Message> list = criteria.list();

for(Message message:list){
    System.out.println(message.getId()
        +"-------"
        +message.getMessageFrom()
        +"-----"
        +message.getFoobar());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this before the end of the day and let you know if it works. Appreciate the response.

Comment: Sorry, I did not. I left work early due to car issues but I will definitely check it as soon as I can and award you whatever points I can (bounty and/or upvotes). Thanks.

Comment: i use the above code but i want to return the distinct chat message where userid = someValue and return only the distinct and last one .. can you tell me how i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty with this query is not so much with Hibernate, per se, but with the relational model in general. In the example, you say you expect rows 1 and 2, but why wouldn't you just as easily expect rows 2 and 3? It would be an arbitrary decision whether to return row 1 or row 3 since they both have the same value in the msgFrom field. Databases won't make arbitrary decisions like this. That's why `distinct` must be applied to the entire list of select columns, not a subset. There are database-specific ways of grabbing the first matching rows. For example, have a look at

[SELECT DISTINCT on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column)

Sometimes there will be a date column that you can use to decide which of the matching rows to return, but again the queries get somewhat complex:

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

[Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

If you don't care about any of the other columns, you can just use a simple `distinct`, combined with Hibernate's constructor syntax (not tested):

```
select new Message(msgFrom) from (select distinct msgFrom from Message)
```

but you have to accept throwing away all the other columns.

In the end, I often end up just doing this in code as a post query filter. Another option is to create a another table, say CurrentMessage, that includes msgFrom as part of the key. There will be more work in keeping this table up to date (you need to update a row everytime you add a row to the Message table) but querying will be much easier.

Comment: Doing it as a "post query filter" is what I don't want to do since I'd have to do that on the app server. See my edit..

Comment: Do you have any additional criteria on your query?  As James said, returning record 1 vs 3 is totally arbitrary as far as the database is concerned which is why he recommended doing it app-side.

Comment: @jeff I understand that it is arbitrary, but it does not matter for my use case. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
DetachedCriteria msgFromCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Message.class);
msgFromCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("msgFrom")));
....
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Message.class);
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("msgFrom", msgFromCriteria));
criteria.list();
```

Comment: Thanks James, haven't tried it yet because I'm at a different facility today. I will let you know later on today or tomorrow morning if I have any problems.

Comment: James, unfortunately this did not work for me. It retrieved over 10,000 records even though there are only 10 distinct "msgFrom" values. Has this worked for you in the past..?

Comment: I thought this example would work I must admit. I therefore conclude that you will have to solve this using straight HQL and avoid using the Criteria API. It seems a lot of people have ran into problems using Criteria and distinct together.