# Hibernate to get distinct values of one column and one random row value from another column

Tags: hibernate, projection, hibernate-criteria

```
clm1    clm2
xyz     1
xyz     2
xyz     3

abc     1
abc     2

qwe     5
```

Suppose i have a table like above.
Using something like:

```
criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class)
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("clm1"), "clm1"))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Foo.class))
```

If i use the above criteria i can get Foo.class objects with distinct elements of clm1 set. i.e.

```
clm1
xyz
abc
qwe
```

In the object of Foo.class is there a way to get:

```
clm1    clm2  
xyz     1
abc     1
qwe     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it by using group by property and getting a min of the other column.
Please refer: [Hibernate Criteria -- return records where column is distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943633/hibernate-criteria-return-records-where-column-is-distinct)