# Hibernate criteria. Select all distinct entities

Tags: java, hibernate, distinct

*How can I select all distinct rows in hibernate with all data?*

If I use this way only IDs will be selected but I need all rows with their data

```
session.createCriteria(MyClass.class, "c")
.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.id()))
```

If I use another approach it will not be performed on sql level but filtered after. That's is not good solution if I need to upload 10 000 rows.

```
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple properties as in [Using Hibernate's Criteria and Projections to Select Multiple Distinct Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196243/using-hibernates-criteria-and-projections-to-select-multiple-distinct-columns)

```
 ProjectionList projList = new ProjectionList();
 projList.add(Projections.property("id.state"));
projList.add(Projections.property("id.uspsCity"))
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
```