# Get all distinct values in spring data based on dynamic column name provided

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data

If my table consists of col1, col2, col3 ....

Then if I have to get all the distinct values of col3( decided on runtime)

Answer (score 0):

1. Spring Data **does not provide any data calculations** - it just translate declarative method invocation/JPQL query to SQL (If you use relational DB under Spring Data). So distinct query will be translated to SQL `DISTINCT` operator.
2. You can use [Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159151/specfiy-columns-which-should-be-considered-for-distinct-calculation) **if you need distinct result set on DB level by dynamically assigned field**. You can use *Reflection API* and pass `Field` object which will be used in Criteria query builder.
3. Another way is to invoke `findAll()` on your Spring Data repository to retrieve **all table records**, and then [remove duplicate by concrete field in your java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property).