# Get all distinct values based on a dynamic column name - Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to get all distinct values in a particular column. Normally this would be done using the `@Query` annotation by writing a select with the particular column name.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.columnName FROM #{#entityName} t")
Set<Object> findDistinctValues();
```

However the column name is dynamic. I need to search for distinct values using the column name argument. Also the repository is generic.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.:columnName FROM #{#entityName} t")
Set<Object> findDistinctValues(@Param("columnName") String columnName);
```

This doesn't work as the syntax is correct.

I've tried using `CriteriaBuilder` instead but it always returns the enter row instead of one column. This would mean I would need to use reflection to get the data I need out of the row as I only have the column name.

Is it possible to use Spring JPA to do this? If not, what is the best alternative method?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159151/specfiy-columns-which-should-be-considered-for-distinct-calculation for doing this with CriteriaBuilder

Comment: @Turo doesn't criteria builder always return back the entire entity? I need just the column contents in a set.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can specify what you wan't as result, as shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just remove the short name of table 't' and leave it like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT :columnName FROM #{#entityName}")
Set<Object> findDistinctValues(@Param("columnName") String columnName);
```

If the first option didn't help you can remove this entityName by passing with @Param as you did to columnName and add a native query to dynamically find value :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT :columnName FROM :tableName", nativeQuery = true)
Set<Object> findDistinctValues(@Param("columnName") String columnName, @Param("tableName") String tableName);
```

Comment: In the first example if you pass `example-column` in as the param the result would always be a set containing `example-column` instead of the content. 
I believe that would also happen in your second example as it would run `SELECT DISTINCT `columnName` ...` too.